# New Line while inserting into VARCHAR2 column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

> I have a requirement where i need  to prepare data for email ,So i   populate
>   data into  column of table having VARCHAR2(4000) as definition, Now what i want, is to 
>   insert it into new line wherever i want to .

```
 begin
 v_email := v_email ||--new line--??;
 end;
```

Suppose i am preparing email text 'List of all blocked transaction id ' ..in one line
1)transaction_id  ....in another lin e
2)transaction_id .....in another line.

> > I am using oracle as rdbms .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the ASCII code and the CHR function to do this.

Here's the entire list. http://www.asciitable.com/

```
SQL> conn rc/rc@orcl102
Connected.
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello..' || chr(10) || 'how are you...');
  3  end;
  4  /
Hello..
how are you...
```

Comment: You might also consider using `'Hello..' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'how are you';` if you want dos/windows style line ending (CR+LF),  instead of unix style (LF). You can use any combination as long as whole emaile message uses the same line ending style.

Comment: @Rajesh :Sorry Thanks to you too,dint see your name in solution :)