# How to split string in Oracle SQL by word

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string which contains a Word **SPLIT_HERE** at multiple places. I want to split this string into multiple rows by **SPLIT_HERE**.
I can only find a way to split using comma or semicolon or a single character delimiter but cannot figure out a way to split by a word.
Is there a way to do so ?

Example String:

```
The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE SPLIT_HERE function replaces a sequence SPLIT_HERE of characters.
```

Desired Output:

```
The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE 
function replaces a sequence 
of characters.
```

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE SPLIT_HERE function replaces a sequence SPLIT_HERE of characters.', 'SPLIT_HERE', 1, LEVELS.COLUMN_VALUE) A
FROM dual 
CROSS JOIN TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2)AS sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
```

Comment: You need to use a pipeline table function. I haven't got a function at hand. See here  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Comment: Multiple rows (different rows in the table, or in the query output), or multiple lines of text (a string with newline characters in it, but still a **single** string, in a single row of a table or query output)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
SELECT LEVEL AS element
       , REGEXP_SUBSTR(te_xt,'(.*?)( SPLIT_HERE |$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) AS el_val
FROM test
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(te_xt, ' SPLIT_HERE ')+1;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=de97f2c48884dc01d566fb74b254ccac)

Comment: Very good usage of regex. Thanks for the today' s lesson :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple (fast) string functions (instead of slow regular expressions) inside a recursive query:

```sql
WITH bounds (value, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         INSTR(value, 'SPLIT_HERE', 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         epos + 10,
         INSTR(value, 'SPLIT_HERE', epos + 10)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS match
FROM   bounds;
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE SPLIT_HERE function replaces a sequence SPLIT_HERE of characters.' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MATCH |
> | --- |
> | `The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE` |
> | `function replaces a sequence` |
> | `of characters.` |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=244d3515b63b22244db490274e7c9fd8)*

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `replace` function since you want to replace a literal string. No need for `regexp_replace`.

```sql
select replace('The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE SPLIT_HERE function replaces a sequence SPLIT_HERE of characters.',
               'SPLIT_HERE',
               chr(10)) as RESULT
  from DUAL
```

Result is:

```
RESULT
-----------------------------
The Oracle/PLSQL REPLACE
 function replaces a sequence
 of characters.
```

Refer to this SO question: [New Line while inserting into VARCHAR2 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036763/new-line-while-inserting-into-varchar2-column)